# Python script to check whether pip,python and adb is installed, if not it should install it

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I am creating a script which will look in the Linux system whether python pip is installed or not?

Checking part is done in my code but I am stuck at installing part if not present.
I tried Sub Process and OS module but still no success.
The problem I am facing is we need to use Super User command to install it, but how do I pass the Super User password.

```
import subprocess

def python_install():
    subprocess.call("sudo apt-get python3", shell=True)

python_install()
```

When running nothing is showing in the terminal and also the execution doesn't stops, when I run the same command in terminal it ask for Super User password.

How to make it to work?

Comment: Just try importing pip.

Comment: A short example for it will be really helpful.

Comment: Sure. `import pip`